# Why is my if elif statement only working for my if statement?

Tags: python, finance

I am continuing on with a bigger project and for this part I am trying to use wallstreet to pull the implied volatility of a certain call or put for options trading. I am able to get it to work individually for calls and puts, but not when I combine them to make it one action.

input variables like aapl 180 call 5 days till expiration -> use an if elif statement for the functions for calls and puts to get the respective IV -> return that IV as a variable for further math in a different section

here is an example of the latest that I have. Any help is appreciated I am newer to coding so if this is obvious apologies.

And for reference my problem is that when I run the call and put functions separately they give two different numbers, but like this regardless of a P or C input, i get the value for calls.

Thanks.

```
from wallstreet import Call, Put
import datetime
from datetime import date

ticker = "tsla"
K = 900
today = date.today()
expiry = today + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
y = expiry.year
d = expiry.day
m = expiry.month
CorP = "P"

if CorP == "c" or "C":
    call = Call(ticker, d=d, m=m, y=y, strike=K)
    sigma = call.implied_volatility()
elif CorP == "p" or "P":
    put = Put(ticker, d=d, m=m, y=y, strike=K)
    sigma = put.implied_volatility()

print(sigma)
```

Comment: I think you mean `CorP == "c" or CorP == "C"`. `CorP == "c" or "C"` is interpreted as `(CorP == "c") or "C"` and is always true.

Comment: Wow that literally worked perfectly, answered within like two minutes. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a logic error in your code,

replace the line

```
if CorP == "c" or "C":
```

with

```
if CorP == "c" or CroP == "C":
```

and same with `elif` part

replace

```
elif CorP == "p" or "P":
```

with

```
elif CorP == "p" or CorP == "P":
```

Comment: Or , you can use ```CorP in ["p","P"]:```  or ```CorP.lower() == "p"```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `lower()` function to simplify your if statement

```
if CorP.lower() == "c": # Converts capital "C" to lower "c" and runs if statement
    call = Call(ticker, d=d, m=m, y=y, strike=K)
    sigma = call.implied_volatility()
elif CorP.lower() == "p": # Converts capital "P" to lower "p" and runs if statement
    put = Put(ticker, d=d, m=m, y=y, strike=K)
    sigma = put.implied_volatility()
```